# Taxonomy term AND (,) operator does not work

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

In contextual filters, with

- validator = taxonomy term
- Filter value type = term ids separated by , or +
- allow multiple values = true

Giving argument **"1+2"** works as espected: *OR* operator

Giving argument **"1,2"** works as **"1+2"**: *OR* operator instead of expected *AND* operator

In both cases, conditions uses operator "IN":
**WHERE (( (field_data_field_tags.field_tags_tid IN('1', '2') ) )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN ('flickr_photo')) )))**

This is the contextual filter part of my view:

```
/* Contextual filter: Content: Tags (field_tags) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['id'] = 'field_tags_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_tags';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['field'] = 'field_tags_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['default_action'] = 'empty';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['default_argument_skip_url'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['specify_validation'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['validate']['type'] = 'taxonomy_term';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['validate_options']['vocabularies'] = array(
  'tags' => 'tags',
);
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['validate_options']['type'] = 'tids';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['validate_options']['transform'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['validate']['fail'] = 'empty';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['break_phrase'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_tags_tid']['not'] = 0;
```

How can I set a *AND* filter? I want to display contents with all values of *tags*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not the best with deciphering exported settings, but I think you should remove that Contextual Filter and use "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" instead.  Make sure you tick "Allow multiple values" under the More section.  That will result in a chain of `AND` clauses in the `WHERE` for the view (well, it does in one that I just looked at).

Comment: I'm using contextual filter because I need to pass tids as argument in `views_embed_view("gallery", "default", $gallery_arguments);` and not exposing selection to user or making it static.

Comment: Ok! "Contextual Filter" + "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" works! Thanks

Comment: I think you are using the wrong contextual filter.  I have a project where I am essentially doing the same thing, though I am using $view = views_get_view() and $view->set_arguments(explode(",", arg(X)); to generate it.

Comment: I had the same problem, this works. you should select `Term IDs separated by , or +` as `Filter value type` to make `Allow multiple values` works

Answer (score 0):

Set them as separate arguments, and it will filter to only things where both match.

Comment: I need to pass a variable number of tids. Like "1,2,3" or "1" or "5,7,96,36". Anyway... isn't this an unexpected behavior?